# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - Google image like preview and description

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a design which I am doing with twitter bootstrap 3.

I have a grid of images. When I click one of the images, I need the ones below the row of the clicked image to slide down to open a div that would show description of that image.

Something like this [link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/).

I couldn't make this example to work with bootsrap 3.

I need some help with this.

Ok I got this far.

[Click this link for bootply link.](http://www.bootply.com/134032)

I got it to work in the basic level but now I'm having some trouble with the css. The boxes switch places. Also if I change the css of `.og-expanded` to `float: none;`, the third div drops below the slide.

```
.og-expanded{
    float: left;
    /*float: none;*/
    position: static;
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Baghoo thanks for the reply. I have edited the question and added a link of the code that I have got so far. I'm stuck on an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this..

http://bootply.com/133532

It uses jQuery to show/hide the appropriate hidden description following each row of images. You'd need to add a larger 2nd version of each image in the "description" cells.

Comment: I need to make it responsive, so putting it in rows is a bit difficult proposition. I'll post an example of the way I am trying to tackle this in few minutes. Will post a bootply link.